# SQL Results as PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to solve this. Maybe this is absolutly incorrect, I need some help.

I have a table like this:

```
INSERT INTO `municipios` (`id`, `provincia`, `municipio`) VALUES (1, 1, 'Alegría-Dulantzi'), (2, 1, 'Amurrio'), (3, 1, 'Añana'), (4, 1, 'Aramaio'), (5, 1, 'Armiñón'),
```

And this is my handler:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM municipios WHERE provincia='1'";
$result = mysql_query($query);      
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {                 
    $groups = array(
    $row{'id'} => array(
        'name' => $row{'municipio'},
        'description' => 'Agrupación electoral de ' . $row{'municipio'},
        'status' => 'public',
        'enable_forum' => 1,
        ),
        );
}
```

With this I got just the last result. I have tried another options, but doesn´t work.

Comment: Use of my `mysql_*` is not recommended. It is *deprecated* and will **not** be supported in later versions of PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should solve your issue:

```
$groups[] = array(
     $row['id'] => array(
        'name' => $row['municipio'],
        'description' => 'Agrupación electoral de ' . $row['municipio'],
       'status' => 'public',
       'enable_forum' => 1,
     ),
  );
```

However, may i suggest your use PDO. There is a pretty good article http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/ that should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer... but I tried this before, and doesn´t work. The groups are created, but there is not any description, name... this is the result in the sql table:

INSERT INTO `wp_bp_groups` VALUES (1, 1, '', '', '', '', 1, '2013-05-05 08:56:26');
INSERT INTO `wp_bp_groups` VALUES (2, 1, '', '', '', '', 1, '2013-04-25 02:32:08');
INSERT INTO `wp_bp_groups` VALUES (3, 1, '', '', '', '', 1, '2013-05-03 22:22:55');

I will try PDO. Thank you again.

Comment: Same trouble with PDO. Groups are created, but no data inside. This is my code:

    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); 
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * FROM municipios WHERE provincia=1');
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
$groups[] = array(
     $row['id'] => array(
        'name' => $row['municipio'],
        'description' => 'Agrupación electoral de ' . $row['municipio'],
       'status' => 'private',
       'enable_forum' => 1,
     ),
  );
}

Comment: what is the output of `$row` ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this an issue with the way you're appending the groups array? I think your overwriting the array every time u set a value. Try using array_push() to append to groups.

Let us know of that helps!

array_push()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php